# Basic styling of jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am a beginning user of jquery. I see that even the most simple questions in this forum tend to be rather advanced of my understanding, but I am at a loss for finding the solution to my specific problem elsewhere. I have looked for about an hour here, and I can't find a real solution to my issue (as it is largely just inexperience).

I have downloaded all of the files associated with jScrollPane, and have dropped the 'script' and 'styles' folders into my site's folder (my site is local). I simply want to make my scrollbar more narrow and a different color, and I can't seem to figure out exactly how that's done.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
{showArrows: true
    });
});

</script>
</head>
```

The show arrows action works, but I can't make any other changes the way I would expect to with CSS (width, color). I see that jquery.jscrollpane.css contains classes for the selectors that I want to manipulate, but I don't know how to apply them. The only selector that appears in my html is:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
```

I don't know how to bring .jspVerticalBar for example, into my html so that it can be styled. All I know how to do is use it as a class in the previously mentioned div, and I can see that that is the wrong application.

Hopefully I have made my question clear. Thanks in advance for taking the time to explain what I'm sure is a very obvious rookie error.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across your question, but if you're still looking for an answer…

THe styling of jscrollpane is in the css file "jquery.jscrollpane.css". The styles that set the width of the track are ".jspVerticalBar" & ".jspHorizontalBar". 
If you are using arrows as well, these also affect the track: ".jspVerticalBar .jspArrow" & ".jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow". 
The default "px" in all these is "16px". You will need to change all four to the same value to make the track narrower.

To change the colours, it's the background that sets the colour. I'm using the lozenge style, so haven't altered these in "jquery.jscrollpane.css" itself, only in the lozenge css.

If you're using arrows from jquery ui (the square png of icons) you'll have to alter the position of the arrows by adjusting the coordinates of ".jspArrowUp" etc. to centre them.